# KDE - Krunner on Multimonitorsetup

Tags: 16.04, kde, krunner

I'm on a two monitor setup. Its very annoying that when I type Alt+F2 to start krunner it always is displayed on the left upper corner of the left monitor. My main monitor is the right monitor and if I'm on a program on this montitor and run Krunner, its very annoying. Does anybody know what to do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a solution, very similar to this one: https://superuser.com/a/1075753/288688

You can create a rule for the `krunner` window: `System Settings` > `Window Behavior` > `Window Rules` > `New...`

For `Window class (application)` you select `Exact Match` and enter the name `krunner`. On the `Size & Position` tab, you enable `Position` with `Apply Initially`.

Now here comes the trick: For the first coordinate, you need to enter a number *larger than your left screen's horizontal resolution*. This way, the window will appear on the right screen. The point is that your multimonitor setup counts as one big screen.

For example, I entered `2600,0`, and after clicking on `OK` and `Apply`, my krunner appears neatly on the right screen.

Comment: @alabamajack Please note that this does not seem to be the default beavior. Alt + F2 always shows krunner on the screen I last clicked on (although I am on 17.04).